# Do Argentinian ATMs only accept 4 digit pins?

Tags: payment-cards, argentina, atms

I heard that ATMs in Argentina only accept 4 digit pin. However, both my credit card and my maestro card have 6 digit pins. Should I change the pin to a 4 digit pin before going to Argentina?

Comment: And in case you encounter the reverse situation - ATMs requiring 6-digit PINs - the general rule is to add two zeroes on to the end of your 4-digit PIN. You should confirm this with your bank as well though.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about personal finance or so.
 

Comment: As an aside, you probably shouldn't be using ATMs in Argentina in the first place, because thanks to Kirchner's shenanigans the official exchange rate is almost 50% worse than the black market one. https://flightfox.com/tradecraft/argentina-black-market

Comment: rofl, did you try the ATM card? care to share experience to make this question usefull to others in the future?

Comment: I'll fly to Argentina right after Christmas. Then I'll report.

Comment: I'm back from Argentina. AS @user1712 already mentioned, HSBC accept 6 digits pin codes, but most other ATMs do not. Since it is a little bit cumbersome to just use HSBC ATMs, I would strongly recommend to change the PIN to 4 digits before going to Argentina.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They have [HSBC](http://www.hsbc.com.ar/es/) in Argentina, HSBC ATMs can deal with 6 digits pin code (first hand experience in various countries since I hold an HSBC card with 6 digits pin code). I think it is safe to assume that you can use your card with 6 digits pin code at least in HSBC's ATMs, also I have noticed that all HSBC ATM machines use the same software.

Comment: Just a word of warning. Relying on speculations and assumptions can bring about unplesant surprises.

Comment: @user3470 you are absolutely right. But there are no sources only leaving assumption the only option.

Comment: @user3470 I saw your answer and I think it is legit.

Comment: I think the same. But there is a person who does not seem to agree.